# C# Asp.net core middleware for redirecting URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-core

I wrote a small middleware for redirecting between WWW URLs.

The most important thing that I want to change is to make it super fast.

Here's what it is doing:

If the host is localhost or mywebsite.com without any subdomains and without www, it will redirect to www.localhost or [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com).

If the host starts with www. AND has subdomains, it will redirect to a url without www.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
 
namespace Website.Middlewares
{
 
    public class WWWRedirectionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
 
        private string _domain;
        private int _https_port;
 
        public WWWRedirectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
 
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
 
            var request = context.Request;
            var response = context.Response;
 
            var host = request.Host;
 
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
            {
                _domain = "localhost";
                _https_port = 5001;
            } 
            else
            {
                _domain = "seaoftools.com";
                _https_port = 80;
            }
 
            // Redirect to www domain if url is home page
            if (host.Host.Equals(_domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                host = new HostString("www." + host.Host, _https_port);
 
                var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
                    "https", 
                    host,
                    request.PathBase,
                    request.Path,
                    request.QueryString);
 
                response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
                return;
            } // Redirect to non-www domain if url is with a subdomain 
            else if (host.Value.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                     && Regex.Replace(host.Host, @"www.|" + _domain, String.Empty) != String.Empty)
            { 
                host = new HostString(host.Host.Replace("www.", String.Empty), _https_port);
 
                var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
                    "https", 
                    host,
                    request.PathBase,
                    request.Path,
                    request.QueryString);
 
                response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
                return;
            }
 
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
 
}
```

What should I change to make the middleware run faster?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Reviews generally require more code than debugging, please include the entire class in the question.

Comment: @pacmaninbw stack exchange shows me an error when I add the full code so I posted only the main part of the code and the full code I posted in a link to paste bin

Comment: “_stack exchange shows me an error when I add the full code_” - what do you mean by “stack exchange”? is that on code review or another site like stack overflow?? what is the error?

Comment: the error was “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted” but now it's fixed I added the whole code @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ

Comment: To anyone in the close vote queue, @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick remarks:

- `_https_port`: do not use underscores in variable names etc., except at the start.
- `_https_port = 80;` The HTTPS port is most definitely not port 80.
- The logic to fill `redirectUrl` and then redirect is duplicated. It should be a method that gets called. I'd move the "compile new host value in these specific cases" logic to a method and return the resulting `HostString`, then compare that `HostString` to the existing `host` and execute the redirect if they're different.
- The string `"www."` is repeatedly used. It would be better to store it in a `const string`. Same for `"https"`.
- In one if you say `host.Host`, yet in the other you say `host.Value`.
- Microsoft has guidelines against using more than three capital letters in a row. So `"WWW"` should become `"Www"` when it is part of a class name or method name etc.

Comment: I am wondering if what you desire couldn't be done better through https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module . Or see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 .

Answer (score 3):

If you add `IWebHostEnvironment` as a dependency to the middleware class, you can simplify the environment check by this:

```c#
if (webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final code after all of the optimization:

````cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Website.Middlewares
{
    public class WwwRedirectionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        private string _domain;
        private int _httpsPort;

        public WwwRedirectionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _next = next;

            _domain = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? "localhost" : "seaoftools.com";
            _httpsPort = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? 5001 : 443;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            bool IsRedirectNeeded = false;

            var request = context.Request;
            var response = context.Response;

            var host = request.Host;

            string WwwString = "www.";

            string HostWithoutWww = host.Host.Replace(WwwString, String.Empty);

            string HostWithWww = WwwString + host.Host;

            // Redirect to www domain if url is home page
            if (host.Host.Equals(_domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                host = new HostString(HostWithWww, _httpsPort);

                IsRedirectNeeded = true;
            } // Redirect to non-www domain if url is with a subdomain
            else if (host.Host.StartsWith(WwwString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && host.Host.Split(".").Length > 2)
            {
                host = new HostString(HostWithoutWww, _httpsPort);

                IsRedirectNeeded = true;
            }

            if (IsRedirectNeeded)
            {
                var redirectUrl =
                    UriHelper
                        .BuildAbsolute("https",
                        host,
                        request.PathBase,
                        request.Path,
                        request.QueryString);

                response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
                return;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: If this is for general purpose use, consider that hosts can contain "www." in the name itself, for example: http://hostwww.com is a valid host. Will your middleware do the right thing in that case?